# Access an enum in a declared (and not exported) module in TypeScript once transpiled

Tags: typescript

**TL;DR**

Without exporting a namespace, but only declaring it, I want to access an enum within it. Once transpiled, the namespace is not accessible (it's an undefined object), therefore the enum fail to be accessed (with an error on the namespace).

**Explanation**

I'm setting up a project in TypesScript, and I'd like to avoid importing all the definitions specific to this project. In this snippet, I created a namespace where I'm putting the local definitions for my redux logic.

An extract of the redux declarations (*redux.d.ts*):

```
declare namespace Redux {

    namespace Actions {

        enum TypeKeys {
            REDUX_INIT          = '@@redux/INIT',
            BOOTSTRAP           = 'BOOTSTRAP',
            CORPUS_LOADED       = 'CORPUS_LOADED',
            ...
        }
        ...
        interface Definition {
            doSomething(): void;
            ...
        }
        ...
    }

    namespace Store {
        interface Definition { ... }
        ...
    }


}
```

Which allows me to avoid importing the definitions in all my code (e.g. in `const mapStateToProps = (state: Redux.Store.Definition) => state;` in my top level component, I don't have to import any *Redux* namespace).

Moving to the problem, I wrote this reducer (*corpusReducer.ts* extract):

```
// Note: no need to import Redux!
export default (state: Redux.Store.CorpusManagement, action: Redux.Actions.ActionTypes): Redux.Store.CorpusManagement => {

    switch (action.type) {

        case Redux.Actions.TypeKeys.CORPUS_LOADED:
            return { corpus: action.payload };

        default:
            return state === undefined ? { corpus: { documents: [] } } : state;

    }

};
```

Once transpiled, I'm getting the error *ReferenceError: Redux is not defined* for the line `case Redux.Actions.TypeKeys.CORPUS_LOADED`.

My suspect is that `Redux` is not available at runtime because, since a namespace, belongs to the TypeScript world. `TypeKeys`, on the other hand, it's an enum, which should have a mapping in JavaScript, therefore my expected behaviour would be that the enum would still be accessible once transpiled.

If I add an export (changing the line into `declare namespace Redux`), the file is "promoted" to be a module, but then I need to import it everywhere in my code.

**Question**

How can I access the enum avoiding the export clause (and therefore to explicitly import the module everywhere)? Is there any good practice I'm not following?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enums use the enum object to hold the values at runtime. This means that if this object is not accessible the code that depends upon it's existence will fail as you discovered.

Your best solution is to make sure that object is exported. Add an extra module that holds the enum and import that.

If this is not possible you could use a const enum in the declarations. Const enums do not depend on the existence of the object as whenever the compiler encounters a reference to an enum value the actual value will be hardcoded in the generated JS.

```
const enum TypeKeys { // No code for const enums is generated.
    REDUX_INIT = '@@redux/INIT',
    BOOTSTRAP = 'BOOTSTRAP',
    CORPUS_LOADED = 'CORPUS_LOADED',
}


let d = TypeKeys.BOOTSTRAP; // All enum references are replaced with values, so this becomes var d = "BOOTSTRAP"
```

You should take care with this approach as this means all values are hardcoded in your JS and any change to the enum will require you to rebuild any code taht references the enum.

**Edit**

Full code that works for me:

```
// definitions.d.ts
declare namespace Redux {

    namespace Actions {

        const enum TypeKeys {
            REDUX_INIT          = '@@redux/INIT',
            BOOTSTRAP           = 'BOOTSTRAP',
            CORPUS_LOADED       = 'CORPUS_LOADED',

        }
        interface Definition {
            doSomething(): void;
        }
        interface ActionTypes {
            type: TypeKeys
            payload: any;
        }
    }

    namespace Store {
        class CorpusManagement {}
    }
}

// usage.ts
/// <reference path="./definitions.d.ts" />
export default (state: Redux.Store.CorpusManagement, action: Redux.Actions.ActionTypes): Redux.Store.CorpusManagement => {

    switch (action.type) {

        case Redux.Actions.TypeKeys.CORPUS_LOADED:
            return { corpus: action.payload };

        default:
            return state === undefined ? { corpus: { documents: [] } } : state;

    }

};
```

The output:

```
(...)
(function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    /// <reference path="./definitions.d.ts" />
    exports.default = (state, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case "CORPUS_LOADED" /* CORPUS_LOADED */:
                return { corpus: action.payload };
            default:
                return state === undefined ? { corpus: { documents: [] } } : state;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I'd be fine with the rebuilding requirement (this declarations would be local to this project and self contained), but the "const" doesn't do the trick. :( 

Furthermore, if I add an "import" clause, the file becomes a proper module, which then bring me back to what I'd like to avoid: importing all the declarations in all my project files

Comment: @pierpytom it should work without the import, and without the export in the namespace. What do you mean `const` does not do the trick. What JS is generated when you access the a member of the enum ?

Comment: That's what the js looks like:

`function(e, t, n) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(t, "__esModule", {
        value: !0
    }),
    t.default = function(e, t) {
        switch (t.type) {
        case Redux.Actions.TypeKeys.CORPUS_LOADED:
            return {
                corpus: t.payload
            };
        default:
            return void 0 === e ? {
                corpus: {
                    documents: []
                }
            } : e
        }
    }
}`

The enum is a const, but kept within the namespace.

Comment: @pierpytom I added the code that I tested with. The enum is removed and replaced with value.

Comment: I agree that yours is the expected behaviour, but strangely is not converting it into a string (either if I keep in the namespace, either if I move it out), and I don't have any particular flag in the tsconfig file :/ I'll investigate further on that too ...

Comment: @pierpytom Maybe you have other errors that are preventing the emit ? Have you tried deleting the output `js` to see if it is regenerated ? There should be no flag that prevents the inlining of a const enum

Comment: I'm looking at your solution, the only difference is the `/// <reference path="./definitions.d.ts" />`, which I omitted. I added it, but still I have the error. I'm using TypeScript 2.9.1, if it makes a difference... To play it safe, I always delete the "build" folder, rebuild it (with success), delete the mapping file, and then with Chrome I auto-indent the minified code, no caching involved.

Comment: @pierpytom The only thing I can think of is that the compiler is not picking up the file with the const enum .Const enum have been around since 1.x so I don't think the version is an issue ..

Comment: I'm using create-react-app for typescript, it seems [I'm not the only one](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript/issues/400), and there is a [Microsoft issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16671) ...

Comment: @pierpytom Well that is unfortunate .. sorry .. it was the best option .. :(

Comment: I'm indeed following your suggestion because makes uber sense! I upgraded everything but still no luck, so I have a bit of fight ahead! Worst case I'll import everything in all the files... Btw, any guideline I can follow? The [deep dive](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/deep-dive.html) is interesting, but given I'm not an expert neither in TS nor React, I ended up locking myself with creat-react-app-ts and I'm not entirely happy because I don't really know what's going on behind the scene... (as you can see with this `const enum` bug)

Comment: @pierpytom sorry, no I don't have any written guidelines I can point you to unfortunately.

Comment: Out of completeness, it seems that the problem come from the "declare" keyword. I can repeat the error if I do `declare namespace Foo {
 const enum Bar {
  Hello = 'World'
 }
}` and then I try a `console.log(Foo.Bar.Hello);` even in the same file (just after the export default).

Comment: I found out that the bug appears when the "transpileOnly" options is specified, and the flag is set in a few of the many dependencies of "create-react-app-ts", which is too much to inspect. I'll move to a vanilla webpack and see what happens, but I don't see why your solution wouldn't work, thank! :)